# App in production is missing on the Play Store

Tags: android, google-play

The app which I refer is in production for more than two weeks, I can access it via the link and download it normally, but when trying to get it on the Play Store for its name it is not listed in the results.

When I tried to change the app name began to find the same in the play store using the search, as it should be normally, but to return the original name the same shall not be located.

It does not seem a very common situation, because little material found on the Internet about it, if you know how to solve this and can collaborate with the answer will be very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

Play store searches usually prioritize the most popular apps, and if there are more apps with names similar to yours', you might have to scroll a little bit to get to it. Try changing the name to a more unique one, that should bring it further up the list when searching for it.